# How to remove spacing above the first line of a QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: qt, qplaintextedit

I am working on creating a line numbers widget for a QPlainTextEdit. It is basically a QListWidget. However, I have detected a small space only above the first line of a QPlainTextEdit as you can see in my screenshot.

[image]

How can I remove this space and even know the exact height of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `QTextDocument::setDocumentMargin()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentMargin-prop, which you can access by calling `QPlainTextEdit::document()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document, or `QPlainTextEdit::setViewportMargins()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins to 0. I am not sure which one will work in your case, but these both can be used for creating some blank space around the document, one of them will certainly work.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentMargin-prop worked